# Android resource compilation failed: inner element must either be a resource reference or empty

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I keep getting this error when trying to sync after editing my gradle files:

> Android resource compilation failed Output: 
>   C:\Users\user\Desktop\Git\app_name\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:797:
>   error:  inner element must either be a resource reference or
>   empty.

The following it the gradle file I edited:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app_id"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 2
        versionName "0.1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-js-rhino:1.3.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'

    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**I have tried cleaning, invalidating and restarting and deleting the build folders**

Comment: Looks like you've got an `<item></item>` element somewhere in a `values.xml` that has an invalid value between the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says it all:

> values.xml:797: error: inner element must either be a resource
>   reference or empty.

The compilation issue is related to your resources file `values.xml`. This file has an invalid resource value.

---

Please check this Android [resources guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources).

Answer (score 0):

When I upgrade my android studio and something , I had that error . I searched a lot and finally I find it . just I had to change ids in values

```
<item name="name" type="id">ID</item>
```

to

```
<item name="ID" type="id"/>
```

After that everything was trued I hope that it used for you